# Testing against local network vs testnet

Tags: testing, mocha, waffle

I have a simple test to mint tokens on a newly deployed contract.

While developing, I was testing locally and the test never failed.
Now that the contract is deployed to the testnet, I get a 50% failure rate in my test.

I can check the contract on Snowtrace and see that the mint function was executed properly.

My question is why are the `await`'s not being obeyed?

See the test in question:

```
it("should allow owner to mint tokens", async function () {
    await contract.deployed();
    await expect(() => contract.mint(bobAddress, fiveHundred))
    .to.changeTokenBalance(contract, bob, (500 * (10 ** (decimals))).toString());
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I truly think you should run the mint function first then use the wait method to wait for the transaction to succeed then use "**expect**" to check "**bobAddress**" has the **fiveHundred** amount in its balance :>

```
    await (await contract.mint(bobAddress, fiveHundred)).wait();
```

Comment: Very much appreciated.
It's irrational to think you need to use `wait()` at the end of 2(!) `await`'s

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this as well. the solution is to wait for the value to update.

Since I work in Python, you'll need to translate this to JavaScript...

```
while contract.owner() != bob: # assuming bob is the owner.
    time.sleep(1)

contract.mint(etc, etc)
```

I'm pretty sure our development environments are interacting with the contracts before they are actually ready even if we do use async.

Comment: With a delay or a `.then()` or  `.done()`?
What was your approach?

Comment: updating my answer

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. You saved me hours of frustration!